# can't use yahoo.co.uk mail with apple mail

Tags: macos, apple-mail, yahoo-mail

When I try and set this up in Apple Mail it says it cannot connect to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For accounts based in the uk (blah@yahoo.co.uk) make sure to remove the "plus." at the beginning of the SMTP and POP servers that are provided on subsequent pages of the setup dialog

Comment: You answered your own question in under a minute?

Comment: @Daniel - Answering your own questions is quite OK. If you spend ages figuring something out, why not share it?

Comment: @Nifle I know. I was just wondering, it's such an uncommon sight.

Comment: @Daniel - what's wrong with doing that? I saw lots of other people with similar issues on the web and thought I'd post my solution here due to it being one of the better tech support sites on the web.

Comment: @adolf Nothing's wrong with it. As I wrote above, it's very uncommon (one user posting a question and its answer essentially simultaneously), so I was just surprised.

Comment: Well the 'good news' is that I cannot mark the answer as answer, there is a time delay before this is possible [24hrs?] so others can always jump in with their own 2p/c. Point taken though.